# Assigning constructor's argument to the vector variable

Tags: c++, vector

I have this code:

```
class Entry
{
protected :
    string itemName;
    vector<string> allItems;

public :
    Entry(string item) : allItems(item){};
}
```

I want to add the constructor argument to the vector variable `allItems` using maybe `push_back()`. How should I do that:

```
Entry("My Entry Name");
```

And then a variable My Entry Name gets added to the `<vector>`

Comment: "And then a variable My Entry Name gets added to the..." The what?

Comment: Why do you copy the string twice in the constructor? Pass by const reference to avoid copying it.

Comment: @Neil Kirk Thanks for mentioning that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider utilizing [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
Entry(string item) : allItems({ item }){};
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can construct from an initializer list:

```
Entry(std::string item) : allItems({std::move(item)}){};
```

In this case you can also use C++98 only and use the fill constructor but fill with just 1 element:

```
Entry(const std::string& item) : allItems(1, item){};
```

Comment: are you sure about `move`? (sometimes, using it where copy-elision is possible actually inhibits the copy-elision)

Comment: @MattMcNabb [I did have a quick play](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5UVEn7zqXGaNyAKZ) and I don't think in this case the copy can be elided. And by using an initializer list I think there will be second copy that can't be elided. But at least we can avoid two copies.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm prepared to be wrong, I'd be interested to know if moving into an initializer list is good practice or not.